# Working with gRPC - choose between frameworks like Spring or Dropwizard

Tags: grpc-java

We are looking ahead to implement a pure gRPC server backend system with Mongo DB as our datastore. Usually, I would always go in for either Spring or Dropwizard as my java framework but since there does not seem to be any special value add for gRPC in these - I am inclined to keep it simple, lightweight and go as a simple maven java project. Is it the right approach Or would you recommend to go with a framework like Spring/DW and why?

Comment: There is spring integration available. for grpc. I would say give it a try. https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter.

Answer (score 0):

You can auto-configures and runs the embedded gRPC server with `@GRpcService`-enabled beans as part of spring-boot application.
Have a look into https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter

Comment: Thanks. We chose to go with plain Java with Maven for the gRPC thing so as to keep it light weight and till now, we are doing quite okay. Thanks !!

Comment: Hello @AashishSingla , what have you been using for security purposes, I wanted to explore possibility of using graph without spring or any huge framework but we need oauth2 secure authentication in server. suggestions ?